# php foreach loop: parsing values of a form into array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a CakePHP project. I want to merge the values of `$value` into a string/array so I can later merge it with the string "TESTING" then implode the outcome to a single string without spaces!!!

```
<?php 
$merge="TESTING"; ?>
<form method="post" name="payment_form" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
<?php foreach ($fields as $name => $value): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<p>some text<input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>    
</form>
```

How can this be done? Thanks in advance.
EG: Please I want to keep the code as is. Meaning no `for(var i=0;i++...)` loops

#### Example

Let's say the values of the form are **1 2 3 productnr** the outcome should be a string **123productnrTESTING** no spaces just a string.

Well i wanted to send that data to a bank gateway to be processed. So it goes like this
1)Bank has sent me a string (The one called TESTING)
2)I print my form data (with the above code)
3) I need to send that data + the string provided into an imploded string to the bank gateway. Hope that clarifies some things :)

Comment: `$merged = implode($_POST)`?

Comment: What should be the output? Didn't understand from your question.

Comment: lets say the values of the form are "1 2 3 productnr"
the outcome should be a string "123productnrTESTING" no spaces just a string. hope i helped:)

Comment: Annotation: If you work in a cakephp project you should use the form helper for the views.
Do you want to merge the values before sending or after? I am not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well i wanted to send that data to a bank gateway to be processed. So it goes like this
1)Bank has sent me a string (The one called TESTING)
2)I print my form data (with the above code)
3) I need to send that data + the string provided into an imploded string to the bank gateway. Hope that clarifies some things :)

Comment: @ElG Is it not my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would need to add a hidden field `merge` as a last one

#### The form page (View)

```
<?php 
$merge="TESTING"; 
?>
<form method="post" name="payment_form" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($fields as $name => $value): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="merge" value="<?php echo $merge; ?>
    <p>some text<input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

#### The action page (Action Controller)

If you are using CakePHP, you would need to [get `POST` data from the Cake Request object](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html).

```
$merge = implode($this->request->params);
echo $merge;
```

Comment: this seems to be working fine ;) thx for the insight guys.
Guess i need to refresh my cakephp knowledge a bit hehe